# How to efficiently serve JS and CSS in a python application

Tags: javascript, python, css, nginx, gunicorn

I recently deployed a WSGI application(openERP v-8.0) using gunicorn and nginx. I noticed that the first request takes a lot of time (1-2 minutes) but the subsequent requests are very fast.

On opening the developer tools, I noticed that most of the time in the first request is spent in serving JS and CSS (requests like:

- http://mydomain/web/js/web.assets_common/4f12486 etc
- http://mydomain/web/css/web.assets_backend/a27f8d5
- http://mydomain/web/js/web.assets_backend/a27f8d5

Can I cache these requests somehow? Or is there an efficient way of serving these requests?

Thanks

Comment: If serving a JavaScript or CSS file is taking one to two **minutes** then either the files are gigabytes in size or else something is seriously wrong.

Comment: Minify your files. Use CSS sprites when appropriate. I suspect your system is already caching the downloads somehow, since only the first request takes such a long time. There are all sorts of techniques to shrink downloads, but we can't suggest any of them until you narrow down the problem and show us some code.

Comment: @Blazemonger: You can checkout the code [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo). I am using the JS and CSS as they are

Comment: That's not how SO works -- we ask that you put your code *directly in your question* so that it's here for posterity and future visitors can quickly see if it's helpful to their own problems. Furthermore, you need to *reduce the problem to a manageable block of code* -- no one wants to search through entire files to identify a problem that might not even be there.

Comment: Are the JS/CSS files being served directly by nginx, or are those requests being deferred downstream?

Comment: @Blazemonger: Its not possible to share the entire code here. I'll dig deeper and figure out the pain points

Comment: @rchang: I have not added any additional configs for these in nginx. So, I guess they are getting deferred downstream.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty normal for a web server to be slower to respond to the first query than to successive ones, whatever the technology stack, if the first query causes initialization work and successive ones avoid that extra work due to caching, reuse of open DB connections, and the like.

A simple and popular workaround (again, whatever the technology stack) is to send that "first query" internally and innocuously, as soon as you've started up the server (presumably in the same script you use for this starting).

The term of art for this very simple approach is "send the warm-up query".  One can get fancy about it (if different queries are needed to warm up various caches &c) but often even the simplest query can suffice in this role.